# Illuminated SPST Switch

Tags: arduino, matrix

I am building a HID device (for flight/space simulators) with an Arduino Micro that will have a 7 column and 4 row matrix plus 4 axes.  I have the matrix working fine with normal buttons and switches but my design calls for 3 switches to have a LED on them to confirm that the switch is active (these have a red toggle guard on them).

I am using 3x [12VDC Toggle Switch with Safety Cover](http://comingsoon.radioshack.com/12vdc-toggle-switch-with-safety-cover/2750601.html#.VWYk4Hmh0-U&tab=tab1) that I purchased from a RadioShack that was going out of business.  These switches have 3 prongs on them labeled: Power, ACC, and Ground.  If I wire the Power and ACC poles the matrix works fine but the LED does not illuminate.  If I connect the ground pole to the ground on the Arduino, the entire row of switches becomes active while in the off state but behaves correctly in the on state.

I have only been working with DIY electronics for about a month now so my skills are rather limited but I have been trying to find an answer to this now for 4 days.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the datasheet?

Comment: I was not able to find one via web search or on RadioShack's site.

Comment: Are there any markings other than the ones you've mentioned?

Comment: "SCI 12V20A".  SCI led me to http://www.sci.com.tw/products.php?plevel=3&opmid=8&p1=ELECTRIC PART&p2=SWITCH&p3= but I was unable to find the exact model.

Comment: R13-404-AL is the closest to what I have except all of the pins on mine are at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I never confirmed which pins on my breadboard were rows and which were columns.  I was plugging the power pole into the matrix's row instead of the matrix's column.

Here is how I wired it.

- Power -> 220 ohm resistor -> Column N
- ACC -> Row N
- Ground -> Ground

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are hooped.  Although it is possible to drive a LED and read a switch at the same time when both are part of a matrix, it's not trivial to do so.  Especially if the LED is intended to operate from 12 Vdc.

Is there any chance that you can open up the switches and bring the LED leads out separately from the switch?  It might even be possible without taking the switch apart - some of the illuminated switches I've seen make the lamp connection right at the bottom of the switch.

You would then drive the LEDs separately from the switch.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer.  I have no problem going out and getting 3 new switches and using these for something else.  I just wanted to exhaust any potential workarounds before doing so. For now I will use the switches without the LED enabled and just purchase some new switches this weekend.

Comment: You mentioned a possible (difficult) way using reed switches.  How would that work?